# Infinitif vs nom

Tags: verbes, noms

Y a-t-il des différerces entre

> La joie de vivre.

et

> La joie de la vie.

?

De même

> La joie d'aimer.

et

> La joie de l'amour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui!
Dans *la joie de vivre*, l'homme tire sa joie de l'action de vivre. La joie de vivre est une idée affect. Presque une sorte de philosophie.

*La joie de vivre n'est pas un but, c'est un devoir* (Louis Pauwels)

Dans *la joie de la vie* (que l'on rencontre plus souvent au pluriel *les joies de la vie*) on parle des faits / choses / événements qui, dans la vie, peuvent procurer de la joie.

Note bien pour y faire attention que cette dernière expression est souvent utilisée par antiphrase :

*Vider les poubelles, faire la vaisselle... ce sont les joies de la vie.*

Comment: Merci bien. Est-ce le même contraste entre amour et aimer (dans le même context) ? Voir question modifié.

Comment: Pas exactement dans la mesure où *joie de vivre* et *joies de la vie* sont des sortes de locutions figées qui ont pris un sens bien particulier. Il n'en va pas de même avec *joie d'aimer* / *joies de l'amour* . Si tu cherches à généraliser la différence entre l'usage d'un verbe à l'infinitif vs substantif correspondant, dis-toi que infinitif vient du latin *infinitivum verbum* qui signifie : "qui n'a pas de contour précis". Tu peux donc en déduire que l'usage de l'infinitif donnera toujours une idée plus large, plus vague, plus générale que l'usage du déverbal.